# Reading files from Azure Blob Storage by partition

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I got azure blob storage container set up like below

Storage Account--> Container->YYYY/MM/DD/abc01.json

The directory hierarchy creates everyday based on Day. Meaning everyday a new "DD" directory is being created and the new file get loaded in there. The same goes with next month as well.

How can I read this partition structure from a scala notebook, which allows me to read all abc*.json file based on the root directory I pass.

eg: If I want to load all the files for a Month I should be able to do that.

Any help on this is appreciated

Regards,

Maks

Comment: if you can list what you tried?  what were the issue then It will be easier to debug or suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the path as below:

```
wasb://YOURDefaultContainer@YOURStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/YYYY/MM/*/abc*.json
```

You need to specify the **YYYY** and **MM** value and since you want to load all the files for a month you can use wildcard characters.